# JW Player: Black screen before seek in Firefox

Tags: javascript, video, jwplayer, embedding

I'm embedding JW Player (7.9.3) on a page in a very simple implementation:

```
jwplayer("video-container").setup({
  "file": "/example.mp4",
  "image": "/example.jpg",
  "width": "100%",
  "aspectratio": "16:10"
});
```

In Chrome and Edge it works as expected, but in Firefox (52.0.2, 32-bit) the video is black, with only the sound playing. It's only when I seek to a different part of the clip that the video starts to show.

Does anybody know of this issue and a potential fix?

Comment: Try the latest version of JWPlayer which is 7.10.4 (https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/releases). You can also post the issue on the JWPlayer support forums

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is definitely supported. You can upload your video to the JW dashboard even with a free account, and see if the JW transcode works better. Otherwise, you might want to run the mp4 through Handbrake, then try it again.